# Identify your two nonzero solutions to this homogenous system

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: I am given a homogenous equation $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ where $\vec{x}$ is a vector and $\vec{0}$ is the $0$ vector. I have solved it and in parametric vector form it is:

$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5 
\end{pmatrix}=x_2\begin{pmatrix}
1.5\\
1 \\
0 \\
4 \\
0 
\end{pmatrix}+x_4\begin{pmatrix}
4\\
0 \\
-6\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$

The equations are $\:\: x_1 = 1.5 x_2 + 4 x_4;\:\: x_2=x_2 (\text{free});\:\: x_3=-6x_4;\:\: x_4=x_4 (\text{free});\:\: x_5=0$

The question I'm asked, and I can find no reference point in our study materials is to identify my two non-zero solutions to the system. Call them vector $\vec{u}$ and vector $\vec{v}$.

I'm also to determine whether $3 \cdot \vec{u}$ is a solution and whether the sum $\vec{u}+\vec{v}$ of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is a solution. I can't figure out the two solutions part. I'm sure I'll get everything else once I just understand what is being asked.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Here's a [MathJax tutorial](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: The $3u$ and $u+v$ stuff can be solved simply from the nature of the equation $Ax=0$ and vector algebra. Does not even require identification of the matrix $A$ or the solution set. In general with this kind of thing, it may be less confusing to use letters other than variable names (e.g. $s$, $t$) for your free variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let $(x_2 = 0$ and $x_4 = 1)$ and $(x_2 = 1$ and $x_4 = 0)$ give you two solutions $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$

Since we know $A\vec{u} = \vec{0}$ and $A\vec{v} = \vec{0}$

then by the rules of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication):

$A(3\vec{u}) =_\text{(product with a scalar)} 3(A\vec{u}) =3\cdot \vec{0} =\vec{0}$ thus $3\vec{u}$ is also a solution

and

$A(\vec{u} +\vec{v}) =_{\text{(distributivity)}} A\vec{u} +A\vec{v} = \vec{0}+\vec{0} = \vec{0}$

and $\vec{u}+\vec{v}$ is another solution as well.

When you solved your system all solutions are of the form $x_2 \cdot \vec{u} + x_4 \cdot \vec{v}$ for arbitrary $x_2, x_4 \in \mathbb{R}$. When they ask for a nonzero solution, that is because the zero solution $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ is always a solution to any homogeneous system $A\vec{x} =\vec{0}$, namely just plug it in $A\vec{0} = \vec{0} \:\: \text{(true)}$ so it's more interesting when there exists a solution other than $\vec{0}$. You could plug in any $x_2,x_4$ as long as the resulting vector is not $\vec{0}$, and since they ask for two, you would plug in different pairs of numbers for $x_2,x_4$.

Nonzero means a solution $\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \\ x_5 \end{pmatrix} \not= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \vec{0}$ of $A\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ thus $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$ are not *all* equal to zero.

This will all be obvious once you get to basis of the nullspace.

Comment: I am three weeks into this class so forgive what might be a dumb question. The requirement is to find two NON-zero solutions. This looks to me to be two zero solutions, but maybe I'm not understanding the terminology. Also, is it simply a matter of selecting any value for x_1 and x_2? Like just make them 1 and 1 and figure out the solution?

Comment: @Ron The solutions to $Ax=0$ correspond to the $x-$values i.e. the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^5$ you multiply by $A$ *on the left* to get the zero vector.

Comment: @Ron I added to my post, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The two column vectors(let's call them $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$) you found form a basis for the null space of $A$ which means they span the solution space of $Ax=0$ meaning that any linear combination belongs to the solution space. i.e: $k_1\vec{v}_1 + k_2\vec{v}_2$ is also a solution for all scalars $k_1,k_2$